# How to Split the string using Regex using c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to split the string using Regex and struck with a problem. Can someone help here

I have a string `"The Quick <B> Brown fox <AB> Jumped on <Z>"`

I want to return only B, AB, Z as strings.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<(.*)>");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(strMessage))
 {
     MessageBox.Show(match.Value.ToString());
 }
```

but this returns only one message with

> `<B> Brown fox <AB> Jumped on <Z>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use from this regex instead of.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[<](\w*)[>]");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(strMessage))
{
    MessageBox.Show(match.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You probably want (\w?) rather than (\w.). I believe it processes faster an it better expresses what you want